# jQuery 2.1.0 | Better way of delimiting long string and extracting substrings from it

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, delimiter

I have dynamically created li containing divs that contain data...

```
<ul>
<li><div class="master"><div class="note">how are you</div><div class="id">1234</div><div class="name">Paula</div><div class="nameid">MN9478</div><div class="title">My plane</div></div></li>
<li><div class="master"><div class="note">I am good</div><div class="id">5647</div><div class="name">John</div><div class="nameid">MN7649</div><div class="title">My boat</div></div></li>
<li><div class="master"><div class="note">Where are you</div><div class="id">9899</div><div class="name">Janette</div><div class="nameid">MN3995</div><div class="title">My car</div></div></li></ul>
```

... that need to be joined as one string to be appended in div, like so (same order as in li above but use semicolons instead of symbols):

```
<div id="str">how are you$1234@Paula_MN9478*My plane;I am good$5647@John_MN7649*My boat;Where are you$9899@Janette_MN3995*My car</div>
```

I'm currently using $ @ _ * as sub-substring delimiters which I use to split and extract the data, and a semicolon between each substring group ("master" class) which I use to split the groups, but I'd rather use only semicolons for all delimiters since "note" and "title" class divs may contain commas and the same current symbols used to delimit sub-substrings.

1. Is there a clean solution that can handle string creation with only semicolons as delimiters in the order displayed in string sample above?
2. Is there a clean way to reverse the process i.e extract the data from the string and inject the data back into their corresponding divs within each li as displayed above?

Does this require some sorta array formula? I know nothing of such, any pointers or examples will help a lot.

Comment: To create the strings, put them all in an array and use `join(';')`. To reverse it, use `split(';')`, then loop through the array in groups of 5, creating the DIVs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clone supplies both text , or `str` , that was extracted and append with ; to `<div id="str">` and `arr` array. The clone also supplies a "template" , for further processing. At piece , after completion of extraction of text , and adding individual `div` text to array , the clone text is removed - resulting in an "empty" template, see `el.innerText = "";`. At `// reverse process` , saved text at `arr` repopulates "empty" `ul` "template" ; see blue "clone". To repopulate "template" with different data, could supply `$.each()` with different array , having same `.length` as `arr`; e.g.,

`var update = ["abc", 123, .., ..];`

, having same order and length as `arr` , or , `15` , at current "template"; then , replace the original `ul` with the `clone` [(update , replace existing `ul` with `clone` , populated with different `text`)](http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/jhpsz018/6/).

At this jsfiddle [(update , append new "template" to `body`)](http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/jhpsz018/5) , "template" is repopulated with the elements' `className` , instead of the previously extracted and saved `str` ,  as occurs at piece below

Try

```
// clone `ul`
var clone = $("ul").clone();
// create `<div id=str>`
var div = $("<div id=str>");
// `str` , text string
var str = "";
// `arr` , text array
var arr = [];
clone.find(".master div").each(function (i, el) {
    $(el).text(function (_, o) {
        return o + ";"
    });
    // substituted `el.innerText.trim()` for `$.trim($(el).text());`
    str = el.innerText.trim();
    arr.push(str);
    div.append(str);
    // replace `innerText` of `div` elements ,
    // with empty string , save `clone` `ul` as template 
    el.innerText = "";
});
// `str`
str = div.text();
// do stuff with `str`
div.css("color", "blue").prependTo("body");
// log processes
console.log(clone, div.text(), str, arr);

// reverse process
$.each(arr, function(k, v) {
    clone.find(".master div").eq(k)
    .text(function(_, o) {
      return o + v.replace(/;$/g, "")
    });
});
// log processes
console.log(clone.find(".master div").text());
// do stuff with clone , after replacing text
clone.css("color", "blue").appendTo("body");
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/jhpsz018/

Comment: Kool! Question: I need for the data to be injected back to their corresponging divs, therefore that data will replace existing data which differ from the imported one. Did you use clone to simply demonstrate that an import was done?

Comment: Text length will differ between existing target li div class text  and extracted substrings made to replace that text - hopefully that doesn't matter - does your code deal with this?

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/jhpsz018/7/ . `update` is string having 16 words , `split` into array having 15 `length` . Words within string having different `length`s. Could substitute, e.g., `["string a", "string b , string c, string d", "123", "text , text , text",..]` continuing until `0-15` index completed , for `update` at jsfiddle . Piece should function same with varying or arbitrary replacement string length properties.

Comment: Your samples answered my 2 questions. Thx for detailed input.

Answer (score 1):

An array of objects is probably the best way to store your data, where each object has the following shape:

```
var exampleRow = {
  id: 123,
  nameid: "MN9478",
  name: "Paula",
  title: "My plane",
  note: "how are you"
};
```

Then you can access the attributes:

```
exampleRow.id // 123
// or
exampleRow["id"] // Also 123
```

Placing each of these rows in an array gets you the data in a normalized form:

```
var data = [{
    id: 123,
    nameid: "MN9478",
    name: "Paula",
    title: "My plane",
    note: "how are you"
  }, {
    id: 456,
    nameid: "MN7649",
    name: "John",
    title: "My boat",
    note: "I am good"
  }, {
    id: 789,
    nameid: "MN3995",
    name: "Janette",
    title: "My car",
    note: "where are you"
  }
];
```

Then, at that point, you can transform the data into either structure easily:

```
// For the complicated DOM structure
data.map(function(userInfo) {
    // Simplified to make it clear(er) what's going on
    return "<li><div class='master'><div class='note'>" + userInfo.note + "</div><div class='id'>" + ... etc. ... + "</div></li>";
});

// For the single string
data.reduce(function(finalString, userInfo) {
  return finalString + ";" + Object.keys(userInfo).map(function(k) { return userInfo[k]; }).join(";");
}, "");
```

Comment: Awesome! Question: Any suggestion for a clean way to split the string (now delimited only by semicolons) into an array like you suggest as "normalized form" and as I asked via alinea 2, in order for all the above code to work? Thx for expert input.